# How to save xlwt with DateTime in filename

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlwt

I'm trying to save an excel file with the date and time within the filename. I do:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
dtnow = str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", gmtime()))

wb_name = '{0}--template.xls'.format(dtnow)
dest = ('\\').join(source.split('\\')[:-1])
# With the dest variable I'm just finding the destination folder to save in from a source variable that I have from before.

wb.save(os.path.join(dest,wb_name))
```

When I save that, I get this as the saved file:

2018-02-13 14

However if I remove the date and time variable completely and just have

```
wb_name = 'template.xls'
wb.save(os.path.join(dest,wb_name))
```

I get a proper excel file with the extension and everything's fine. I think the colon is causing some sort of error. I'm not sure. Also, after saving, the file shows to be 0 bytes, while the template.xls that saves properly is the correct file size. Why can't I save the excel file with the datetime and have the extension included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most Filesystems you can't have `:` in the filename, simply change your naming:

```
dtnow = str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M", gmtime()))
```

for more information, [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/4464653):

> I know that `/` is illegal in Linux, and the following are illegal in Windows
>   (I think) `*` `.` `"` `/` `\` `[` `]` `:` `;` `|` `=` `,`